# changing from was-ce server to any other server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2

I have created a j2ee project using:

```
1)DB2 (as database server)
2)WAS-CE server to deploy the application
3)eclipse to code.
```

as was-ce server is running too slow I want to change to any other server.

my question is:

can I change to any other server? What are your views about tomcat and sql server? The most important question is what changes should I make in my web app to adapt a different server?Is the changes in the web.config file sufficient to adapt different servers having the same database server?

in hope of a good response.

robin

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to redeploy to any Java EE server that supports the same Java EE version that your WAS-CE server supports.

For a list, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Enterprise_Edition#Certified_application_servers

Comment: please suggest what settings changes should i make in my application to redeploy it in glass fish server...

Comment: In theory you shouldn't have to change anything.  In practice, try to switch and see what happens.

Comment: i think this question was a good question which can help many beginners but no one is answering it in details since a long time